# Octopus Deploy: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

Tags: azure, octopus-deploy

I followed [this guide](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/octopus/) to deploy to Azure through Azure Devops and Octopus Deploy. It worked the first two deploys, but when I did some new changes I now get the following error message:

`The step failed: Activity Deploy an Azure Web App on AspDotNetCore failed with error 'The remote script failed with exit code 100'.`

```
Deploying to Azure WebApp 'MyAPI' in Resource Group 'MyApp', using subscription-id '<Subscription ID>'
Running rollback behaviours... 
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict' 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.DefaultErrorResponseException
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.WebAppsOperations.        
<ListPublishingProfileXmlWithSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__148.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.WebAppsOperationsExtensions. 
<ListPublishingProfileXmlWithSecretsAsync>d__287.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Calamari.AzureWebApp.Integration.Websites.Publishing.ResourceManagerPublishProfileProvider.            
<GetWebDeployPublishProfile>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Calamari.AzureWebApp.Integration.Websites.Publishing.ResourceManagerPublishProfileProvider. 
<GetPublishProperties>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Calamari.AzureWebApp.AzureWebAppBehaviour.<Execute>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Calamari.Common.Plumbing.Pipeline.PipelineCommand.<ExecuteBehaviour>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Calamari.Common.Plumbing.Pipeline.PipelineCommand.<Execute>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Calamari.Common.Plumbing.Pipeline.PipelineCommand.<Execute>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Calamari.Common.CalamariFlavourProgramAsync.<Run>d__4.MoveNext()
The remote script failed with exit code 100 
The action Deploy an Azure Web App on AspDotNetCore failed
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My subscription to Azure was disabled (without notice).

`We've identified suspicious activity in this subscription. To protect your account, we've disabled the subscription. Please contact Azure Support to resolve the issue.`

EDIT: When the Azure subscription was re-enabled (again without notice) I could deploy my package on Octopus and now everything works again as expected.